# Facebook invitation not work in my App

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have used Facebook version is **sdk 4.0.0**

I'll try using below code:

```
 try {

                        String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;
                        appLinkUrl = "Har is my google play/Store Url";
                        previewImageUrl = "hear is my app logo url URL";


                        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                                .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                                .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                                .build();

                        //AppInviteDialog.show(getActivity(), content);

                        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
                        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                                Log.d("Facebook Result",result.toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                Log.d("Facebook Result","Cancel");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                                Log.d("Facebook Error",error.toString());
                            }
                        });
                        appInviteDialog.show(content);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Error Invetation", e.toString());
                    }
```

But hear is not open any dialog box for user invitation also it's not show a any error 
**Not show any `Logcat` msg**

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i need to open invitation page in my app but it's not work properly @leoderprofi